# Icono sobre imagen usando CSS y Material Design Icons

Tags: css, css3, material-design

Tengo el siguiente código:

```css
.stat {
  color: #4c4c4c !important;
  float: left !important;
  font-size: 10px !important;
  line-height: 17px !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  width: auto !important;
}

.stat:hover {
  color: #747474 !important
}

.stat strong {
  display: block !important;
  font-size: 22px !important;
  line-height: 25px !important
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="stat">
    <strong>3333</strong> vic
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="stat">
    <strong>60</strong> 0986001661
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="stat">
    <strong>117</strong> vic.3@gmail.com
  </a>
</div>
```

Quisiera saber cómo puedo alinear un icono en vez de la etiqueta `strong`. Algo como esto:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div>
  <a href="#" class="stat">
    <i class="material-icons">power_settings_new</i> vicsss
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="stat">
    <i class="material-icons">power_settings_new</i> 98988888
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="stat">
    <i class="material-icons">power_settings_new</i> vdddddd@gmail.com
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias @Ivan Botero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es sencillo, tan sólo tienes que hacer que la etiqueta `i` tenga `display:block` y que el texto del enlace `a` esté centrado. Algo bastante parecido a lo que ya tenías (sólo he añadido algo más para que sea algo más vistoso):

```css
a {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
}

a:hover {
  color: #666;
}

i.material-icons {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div>
  <a href="#" class="stat">
    <i class="material-icons">power_settings_new</i> vicsss
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="stat">
    <i class="material-icons">power_settings_new</i> 98988888
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="stat">
    <i class="material-icons">power_settings_new</i> vdddddd@gmail.com
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias Alvaro eso necesitaba :D

Answer (score 1):

```
   <div class="imageWrapper" style="position: relative; width: 195px; height: 195px;">
   <img src="/path/to/image.jpg " alt=.. width=.. height=..style="position: relative; z-index: 1;" />
   <i src="/path/to/play.jpg " alt=.. width=.. height=.. style="position: absolute;left:80px; top: 80px;z-index: 10;" />
  </div>
```

el wrapper debe tener posicion relativa y los hijos o iconos absoluta

Comment: Con la etiqueta `i` supongo que te refieres a `img`, a no ser que quieras hacerlo como lo hace OP (con los iconos de material design) que sería algo diferente

Comment: <i> es para ico y svg me equivoque en el ejemplo, pero son muy similares y puesdes cambiar el tipo de elemento que va dentro del wrapper (imagen de fondo) a lo que sea

Comment: [`<i>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/i) no es similar a `<img/>` y no es para iconos o svg, es para letra en itálica/cursiva. Lo usan diferentes bibliotecas CSS para iconos, y aunque funciona (no con los atributos de esta respuesta), no es el uso para el que se diseñó originalmente.